# scrape docker metrics from inside container

Tags: docker, networking, iptables, socat

I am trying to scrape [docker metrics](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/prometheus/) from inside a container. I have seen the creator of Prometheus doing it this way [see video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDxcEzu62jk&t=1813s). I am not able to reproduce it.

#### Configuration

I have exposed docker metrics page via json config.

```json
{
  "metrics-addr" : "172.17.0.1:4999",
  "experimental" : true
}
```

I have also tried with 0.0.0.0. In any case I am able to curl from the host machine itself with no issues.

```
$ curl 172.17.0.1:4999/metrics | more

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0# HELP builder_builds_failed_total Number of failed image builds
# TYPE builder_builds_failed_total counter
builder_builds_failed_total{reason="build_canceled"} 0
builder_builds_failed_total{reason="build_target_not_reachable_error"} 0
...
```

#### From inside container

However, I am not able to get the same metrics page from inside a container. I have tried to [basi/socat](https://github.com/bvis/docker-socat) image, the same one from the video. I have also tried a handful of other ways like using curl from inside the container and so on.

The image does essentially just one thing

```
ENV IN="172.17.0.1:4999" \
    OUT="4999"

ENTRYPOINT socat -d -d TCP-L:$OUT,fork TCP:$IN
```

#### Start Socat Container

```
docker run --rm -p 4998:4999 basi/socat
2021/04/02 16:27:47 socat[8] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:4999
```

#### curl the Container published port

```
curl localhost:4998/metrics
```

#### Connection just hangs

The `socat` images recognizes the connection, but it hangs for 1-2 minutes and times out.

```
2021/04/02 16:29:53 socat[8] N accepting connection from AF=2 172.17.0.1:57678 on AF=2 172.17.0.2:4999
2021/04/02 16:29:53 socat[8] N forked off child process 9
2021/04/02 16:29:53 socat[8] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:4999
2021/04/02 16:29:53 socat[9] N opening connection to AF=2 172.17.0.1:4999
2021/04/02 16:32:04 socat[9] E connect(5, AF=2 172.17.0.1:4999, 16): Operation timed out
2021/04/02 16:32:04 socat[9] N exit(1)
2021/04/02 16:32:04 socat[8] N childdied(): handling signal 17
2021/04/02 16:32:04 socat[8] W waitpid(): child 9 exited with status 1
```

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

#### Firewall

I am slowly wondering if it could be something in my `iptables` rules. I have posted below `INPUT` and `DOCKER-USER` chain. Those are the only ones I have changed myself.

```
sudo iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 32060 packets, 1810K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 716K 1484M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 599K 1069M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   16  3138 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   12   624 DROP       all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
74921  139M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: ah sorry, this is ubuntu 20

Comment: See the metrics server is on the host and not inside the container. One way you can access the metrics inside the host is to use the host ip and for this you should make the metrics to listen on `0.0.0.0`

Comment: As I mentioned, I have tried with 0.0.0.0 already.  If I use the hostip then I don't need to proxy this, that would be pointless. Then I can just query hostip:4999/metrics directly. The Reason for this proxy setup is as you see in the video to deploy it as service in mode global. Also, the metrics server is running on `docker_gwbridge` and all containers have access to this. Socat is also not saying connection refused as it happens with completely invalid addresses.  Again, in the image from the video its not using hostip.

Comment: How would you even bind the hostaddress with socat from inside the container? The container is its own host in some way right? Only network mode host would make this possible.

Comment: Doing it in network mode `host` will give you that access, but in case you are thinking of of connecting another docker container to this container and expose metrics, that wongt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230677/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-the-fool).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out issues was indeed iptables. The default policy for the `INPUT` chain in this case is `DROP`. Since the container is now trying to reach the host system itself, its traffic will come through the input chain.

So I added 2 simple rules for now, that will allow all traffic in the `INPUT` chain from `docker0` and `docker_gwbridge`.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i docker_gwbridge -j ACCEPT
```

After that I am finally able to query docker metrics from inside the container.

```
docker run --rm curlimages/curl -I -m 10 172.17.0.1:4999/metrics
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; version=0.0.4; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 03 Apr 2021 10:53:12 GMT
```